# Obtaining a string representation of a protocol dynamically

Tags: swift

I'm looking for a way to obtain a protocol name dynamically from the protocol type, without having to use the `@objc` attribute in the protocol declaration.

I know that this works:

```
func keyForProtocol(aProtocol: Protocol) -> String {
    return NSStringFromProtocol(aProtocol)
}
```

but only if the protocol has the `@obj` attribute:

```
@objc protocol Test {}

var key = keyForProtocol(Test.self)  // Key contains "TestApp.Test"
```

however as soon as I remove the `@objc` attribute, compilation fails with this error:

```
'Test.Protocol' is not convertible to 'Protocol'
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Note: the reason why I want to avoid `@objc` is that it doesn't allow usage of *associated types* (i.e. generics in protocol) - in those cases compilation fails with this error: `Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of parameter xx cannot be represented in Objective-C`

Comment: I don't believe this can be done, but I'd be interested to know what you're trying to achieve with it - because whatever it is, it probably won't work either :). I suspect it's best to think of Swift protocols only really 'existing' at compile time; I'm pretty sure no usable protocol information remains in the compiled binary (hence no conformance checks for non-@objc protocols, etc).

Comment: @Sam: I've built a simple dependency injection framework allowing me to bind a protocol to a class type. It's worked fine until I tried to use generics in a protocol, hence the need to get rid of the `@obj` attribute.

Comment: yes, it will work okay with an @objc protocol, but Swift protocols are different, and you can't do much with them at runtime. I'd say you'll need to come up with a different dependency-matching design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently found a solution by implementing the `keyForProtocol` method as follows:

```
func keyForProtocol<P>(aProtocol: P.Type) -> String {
    return ("\(aProtocol)")
}
```

It works with any type, not just for protocols, but I'm ok with that.

Some examples from a playground:

```
protocol Test {}
keyForProtocol(Test.self) // Prints "__lldb_expr_92.Test"

class MyClass {}
keyForProtocol(MyClass.self) // Prints "__lldb_expr_92.MyClass"

keyForProtocol(Int.self) // Prints "Swift.Int"

keyForProtocol(UIView.self) // Prints "UIView"
```

Answer (score 0):

As Antonio said:

```
let protocolDescription = "\(aProtocol)"
```

will return a (sometime strange) protocol name.

I finally completed my task converting back this string to a protocol with:

```
let protocolReference = NSProtocolFromString(protocolDescription)
```

This technique is perfect if you need to retrieve the protocol type from a generic parameter like in this example (a lightweight/homemade dependency manager):

```
class DependencyManager<T> {
  private static func inject(_ aProtocol: T.Type) -> T {
    let application = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! LMApplication
    let dependencies = application.applicationDependencies

    let protocolReference = NSProtocolFromString("\(aProtocol)")
    let dependency = dependencies!.object(for: protocolReference)

    return dependency! as! T
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let object: Protocol = DependencyManager.inject(Protocol.self)
```